# Creating OSX Notifications Xcode 4 Style

Tags: xcode, cocoa, macos, notifications

How can I create the floating, translucent, black notifications Xcode 4 and some other apps use to notify users of events?

This screenshot shows Xcode's "Build Succeeded" notification as an example.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer here [How to implement HUD-style window like Address Book's “Show in Large Type”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446878/how-to-implement-hud-style-window-like-address-books-show-in-large-type/4447132#4447132) could serve as a pretty good starting point. You would want to up the radius on the rounded `NSBezierPath` that's drawn, and set the opacity lower in the window so it matches that of the Xcode notification.

Answer (score 3):

Also checkout the `RoundedFloatingPanel` example project by Matt Gemmell:
http://mattgemmell.com/source/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the code (Open Source) for [Growl](http://growl.info/).

It might give you some ideas.

Comment: See also [QuickSilver](http://code.google.com/p/blacktree-alchemy/). I believe it basically comes down to "create a chromeless window and stick your view in there".