# Transparent rounded window but with opaque controls

Tags: cocoa

I am trying to make a HUD with a transparent rounded window with opaque controls as is commonly seen in apps such as Xcode popups, the native volume control, etc.

I'm using the technique detailed here: [How to implement HUD-style window like Address Book's "Show in Large Type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446878/how-to-implement-hud-style-window-like-address-books-show-in-large-type)
but this renders controls in the view transparent. I've tried setAlphaValue:1.0 on the controls but that has no effect. Searches for other solutions point to Matt Gemmell's RoundedFloatingPanel component. I can't open the project in Xcode 4, but looking at the code as far as I can tell the only difference seems to be in Matt's code he sets the alpha of the window to 1.0 and uses a transparent fill for the NSRect in the view. I tried this but still end up with transparent controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So unsurprisingly, Matt Gemmell's code works just fine and I had made a mistake. I forgot that I was also messing with the alpha of the window elsewhere in my code in order to make it fade out on close.

To to sum it up for others running into this issue, if you set the alpha on the NSWindow the controls in that window will also be transparent. Instead set the alpha on the NSBezierPath fill color in the NSView. Just like Matt Gemmell's code does. :)

Comment: Cool @stdout. I am having this issue also. You should accept your own answer this way! thanks