# NSPanel as HUD Panel - fullscreen makes strange empty space

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit

I have NSPanel window with style Utility panel (gray small title bar). I can fullscreen this window using standard MAC OS X fullscreen feature. But one strange thing happens - the content view of window doesn't use whole screen, there is small empty space, that is high as title bar.

This doesn't happen, when I change my window style to Regular panel (means higher titlebar).

NSPanel parameters designed in Interface builder:
[image: Windows designed in interface builder]

Clipping of fullscreen view of this window. Note empty space - where red arrow points. This **doesn't happen** when I change Style to **Regular panel**.

[image: Fullscreen preview]

Answer (score 0):

Try using NSWindow instead of NSPanel

```
- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSUInteger)windowStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)deferCreation {
       if (self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect
                            styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                              backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:deferCreation]) {

             [self setOpaque:NO];
             [self setExcludedFromWindowsMenu:NO];

        }
        return self;
}
```

This is a [quazi related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4447132/703161)